# PySide Signal "duplicating" behavior

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside, qt-signals

```
from PySide.QtCore import *

class Eggs(QObject):
    evt_spam = Signal()
    print "Loaded"

a = Eggs()
b = Eggs()
print a.evt_spam
print b.evt_spam
print a.evt_spam is b.evt_spam
```

outputs:

```
Loaded
<PySide.QtCore.Signal object at 0xa2ff1a0>
<PySide.QtCore.Signal object at 0xa2ff1b0>
False
```

"Loaded" only printing once (as expected; it is a class variable), but why are 2 instances of the signal being created (if it is also a class variable)?

Comment: Isn't the question academic? It is only important that it works: all instances can emit the signal and all subscribers (all instances connected to the signal) get the signal. I agree that it is interesting. But its not a deficiency, or limiting to most programs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not being printed when you create a class instance, but rather when the class scope is executed. This code will print "Loaded", even though I never made an instance of "Test".

```
class Test:
    print "Loaded"
```

If you want to run code when the class is initialized, take a look at `__init__()`. This code will print "Loaded" when an instance is made, instead of when the class itself is defined.

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        print "Loaded"
```

QT's QObject metaclass appears to be rewriting the class attributes to prevent duplicate signals when you initialize a new instance of the class. Perhaps you can assign the attribute like this:

```
class Test(QObject):
    def __init__(self, signal):
        self.evt_spam = signal

sig = Signal()
a = Test(sig)
b = Test(sig)
```

Or this:

```
class Test(QObject):
    def signal(self, signal):
        self.evt_spam = evt_spam
        return self

evt_spam = Signal()
a = Test().signal(evt_spam)
b = Test().signal(evt_spam)
```

Comment: Yes, I understand this, but why are 2 instances of the signal being created? I'll edit my question to make it clearer.

Comment: `QObject` is a metaclass. My best guess is it's mangling the class attributes. The results are different if you don't inherit from `QObject`, correct?

Comment: If I change `QObject` to `object`, the signal won't work, but the variables point to the same memory location. So that is probably right. What do you think are the chances of this changing (in a future release of Qt)?

Comment: You'd need to talk to the QT developers, but they're probably doing it for a reason. It's a matter of telling you to fix your code vs adapting all of the projects already in existence - the first is far more convenient for the PyQT devs. The metaclass is possibly doing its magic when you init the class, so maybe you can reassign the signal from outside class scope after the fact or use a global?